building a docker image and use it directly without push in azure dev ops
In a azure pipeline I have two steps:

The first step is to build a Docker image (which provides a cross compile environment)

Second step is to build
steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true

- task: DockerInstaller@0
  displayName: Docker Installer
  inputs:
    dockerVersion: '17.09.0-ce'
    releaseType: stable

- bash: |
    docker -t my_image -f path/to/Dockerfile .
  displayName: "Build docker image"

- bash: |
    docker run -ti my_image <some_build_command>
  displayName: "Build application"



The log output looks like:
Resolving "my_image" using unqualified-search registries (/etc/containers/registries.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/my_image:latest...
Trying to pull quay.io/my_image:latest...
Error: 2 errors occurred while pulling:
 * initializing source docker://my_image:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/my_image: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required

 * initializing source docker://quay.io/my_image:latest: reading manifest latest in quay.io/pm-linux-arm64: StatusCode: 404, <!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Foun...

I seems that the worker ignores my docker image.
When doing a 'docker images' before build command it outputs my_image as part of the local docker registry
Does anyone has an idea?

adding "--pull never" in docker run command solved the issue
EDIT: there was a second Problem under the hood. The Docker I am building produces a shell script to run commands using this image. The script is detecting the container-rizer app and selected podman instead of docker. podman did not find the image because it was build using docker .

By adding the --pull never option to the docker run command, it will never pull the image from a remote registry and only use the image if it is already available locally. This prevents Docker from attempting to pull the image from remote registries.  Thanks for sharing the answer. You can accept this as answer.
